# Dell running Windows XP automatically switching on

Tags: windows-xp, power

I have a Dell Dimension 5150 running Windows XP, it has a Intel Pentium dual core 2.8ghz processor and 2gb of ram. It also has 5 users, of which only one is an admin. The others are limited.

Could anyone suggest a reason it might be turning itself on automatically as when ever I get home it is on, having always turned it off the night before, and a way to remedy this.

Comment: Are you shutting down or putting it to sleep/hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dells come with a BIOS option to turn themselves on at a certain time. Look into that.

Comment: Thanks =) that did the trick, looks like someone hda decided to fiddle with the BIOS

Answer (score 3):

I've seen a couple Dell machines that did this, too - check and see whether "Wake on LAN" is enabled in the BIOS. If it is, there might be some network activity that is causing it to turn on by itself.

Comment: Good tip, I didn't even think of this.

Answer (score 0):

another thing to check is to see if there are any Tasks scheduled that are set up to wake the computer when they run